How do I start MediaPlayer from the beginning, if the track is already at the end?
I have an application that lets the user load an audio track, starts and stops it as you wish, and when you close the application it remembers where you left off, so when you open the application, the track loads automatically at the place you left off.
When you reach the end of the track, I use the Media Ended event to let the viewmodel know the track is no longer playing.
However when the user gets to the end of the track and it ends, I would like them to be able to press the start button and for it to reset to the beginning and play again.
Currently, my code just tries to play the track from the current position, which is the end, so it just stops immediately.
I have tried to do a check when you press play, to see if the current position equals the tracks natural duration, and if so, set the position to zero, but the trouble is when I debug, the natural duration is set to Automatic, which means the MediaOpened event hasn't fired. But I'm not sure with my code, how to do this.
XAML file
<Window x:Class="Davids_Library.View.MediaWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
        xmlns:viewModel="clr-namespace:Davids_Library.ViewModel"
        mc:Ignorable="d"
        Title="David's Music Listener" Height="450" Width="800"
        DataContext="{DynamicResource Vm}">
    <Window.Resources>
        <viewModel:LoadedItemViewModel x:Key="Vm" />
    </Window.Resources>
    <Window.InputBindings>
        <KeyBinding Key="Right" Command="{Binding QuickForward}"></KeyBinding>
        <KeyBinding Key="Left" Command="{Binding QuickBack}"></KeyBinding>
        <KeyBinding Key="Right" Modifiers="Control" Command="{Binding LongForward}"></KeyBinding>
        <KeyBinding Key="Left" Modifiers="Control" Command="{Binding LongBack}"></KeyBinding>
        <KeyBinding Key="i" Modifiers="Control" Command="{Binding GetInfo}"></KeyBinding>
        <KeyBinding Key="o" Modifiers="Control" Command="{Binding LoadFile}"></KeyBinding>
        <KeyBinding Key="Space" Command="{Binding StartStop}"></KeyBinding>
    </Window.InputBindings>
    <Grid>
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="Auto"></RowDefinition>
            <RowDefinition></RowDefinition>
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <Grid>
            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"></ColumnDefinition>
            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <Button Content="Open File" Margin="5" Padding="15 5" 
                CommandParameter="{Binding Text, ElementName=textBox}" 
                Command="{Binding LoadFile, Mode=OneWay}"
                ToolTip="Open File"></Button>
        </Grid>
        <Grid Grid.Row="1">
            <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                <RowDefinition Height="Auto"></RowDefinition>
                <RowDefinition></RowDefinition>
                <RowDefinition Height="Auto"></RowDefinition>
            </Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <TextBlock Grid.Row="0" Text="{Binding Source, ElementName=MediaPlayer}"></TextBlock>
            <MediaElement x:Name="MediaPlayer" Grid.Row="1" Source="{Binding FileUri}"
            Width="450" Height="250" LoadedBehavior="Manual" UnloadedBehavior="Stop" Stretch="Fill"
            Loaded="OnMediaElementLoaded" MediaEnded="OnMediaEnded" ></MediaElement>
            <UniformGrid Grid.Row="2" Rows="1">
                <TextBlock Text="{Binding Position}"></TextBlock>
                <Button Content="Play" Margin="5" Padding="5" 
                    Command="{Binding StartStop}"
                    ToolTip="Start / Stop"></Button>
            </UniformGrid>
        </Grid>
        </Grid>
</Window>

And code-behind
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.IO;
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Threading;
using Davids_Library.Services;
using Davids_Library.ViewModel;
using Microsoft.Win32;

namespace Davids_Library.View
{
    public partial class MediaWindow
    {
        private readonly DispatcherTimer? _positionUpdateTimer = new();
        private readonly MemoryStoreService _memoryStoreService = new();

        private readonly Func<string, string, bool> _message;
        
        public MediaWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

            _message = (Func<string, string, bool>)((msg, capt) =>
                MessageBox.Show(msg, capt, MessageBoxButton.OK) == MessageBoxResult.OK);

            if (_positionUpdateTimer != null)
            {
                _positionUpdateTimer.Interval = TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(10);
                _positionUpdateTimer.Tick += OnMediaElementTick;
            }

            Closing += Cleanup;
        }

        private void OnMediaElementLoaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            var loadedItem = (LoadedItemViewModel)MediaPlayer.DataContext;
            loadedItem.GotoTimeAction = ms => MediaPlayer.Position = TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(ms);

            loadedItem.LoadFileExecuted = OpenTrack;

            loadedItem.GetInfoAction = (isPlaying, uri, position) =>
            {
                var message = string.Format("Track {0} is {1}currently playing, and is at position {2}",
                    Path.GetFileName(uri?.AbsolutePath),
                    isPlaying ? "" : "not ",
                    position.ToReadableString());
                _message.Invoke(message, "");
            };

            loadedItem.StartStopRequested = () => 
            {
                if (loadedItem.IsPlaying)
                {
                    MediaPlayer.Pause();
                    _positionUpdateTimer?.Stop();
                    _memoryStoreService.SaveState(loadedItem);
                    loadedItem.IsPlaying = false;
                }
                else
                {
                    MediaPlayer.Position = loadedItem.Position;
                    MediaPlayer.Play();
                    _positionUpdateTimer?.Start();
                    loadedItem.IsPlaying = true;
                }
            };

            var item = _memoryStoreService.LoadDefault();
            if (item == null)
            {
                _message("No track has been loaded yet.", "");
                return;
            }

            _message("Track " + Path.GetFileName(item.Source?.AbsolutePath) + " has been loaded, and is at position " + item.Position.ToReadableString(), "");
            
            loadedItem.FileUri = item.Source;
            loadedItem.Position = item.Position;
        }

        public void OpenTrack()
        {
            var loadedItem = (LoadedItemViewModel)MediaPlayer.DataContext;
            if (loadedItem.IsPlaying)
                loadedItem.StartStop.Execute(null);

            var dialog = new OpenFileDialog();
            var success = dialog.ShowDialog() ?? false;

            if (!success || string.IsNullOrEmpty(dialog.FileName))
            {
                _message("No valid audio file was specified, unable to load", "");
                return;
            }
            
            var filename = dialog.FileName;
            loadedItem.FileUri = new Uri(filename, UriKind.Absolute);
            loadedItem.Position = TimeSpan.Zero;

            _memoryStoreService.SaveState(loadedItem);

            _message("Track " + filename + " has been loaded, and is at the start of the track", "");
        }


        private void Cleanup(object? sender, CancelEventArgs e)
        {
            _positionUpdateTimer?.Stop();

            var loadedItem = (LoadedItemViewModel)MediaPlayer.DataContext;
            _memoryStoreService.SaveState(loadedItem);
        }

        private void OnMediaElementTick(object? sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            var loadedItem = (LoadedItemViewModel)MediaPlayer.DataContext;
            loadedItem.Position = MediaPlayer.Position;
        }

        private void OnMediaEnded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            var loadedItem = (LoadedItemViewModel)MediaPlayer.DataContext;
            loadedItem.IsPlaying = false;
            _message("You have reached the end of the track.", "");
        }
    }
}

It's in the OnMediaElementLoaded method I need to add this code, when I assign the StartStopRequested event to the inline method. These two lines are where it happens
MediaPlayer.Position = loadedItem.Position;
MediaPlayer.Play();
What I need here is some way to check if the track is already at the end, and if so, reset it to the beginning.
Any thoughts how I can do this?
